# Using define() of require.js in text.js html of backbone project

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I create a backbone project with text.js, underscore.js, require.js and backbone.js. I separated `header`, `body` and `footer` of my web page into html file using `text.js`.

Here is my view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
"underscore" ,
"backbone" ,
"text!templates/Layout/footer.html",
],function($ , _ , Backbone, FooterTem){
  var serviceTag = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
    },
    render : function(){
        var footerTem = _.template(FooterTem);
        $("#webfooter").html(footerTem);
    }
  });
  return serviceTag;
});
```

Then in `footer.html` of text.js, I want to call the other third party function (the footer is used almost every web page) :

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="containerFooterUL">

        <%
            define(["jquery" ,
                    "webconfig",
                    "content"
                    ],function($ , WebConfig, Content){

                var content = new Content();
                console.log(content.getContentType());
                console.log("1");
            });

        %>
   </div>
</div>
```

The `console.log` didn't work, Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `define` in your template to `require`. The `define` call is for *defining* modules. If you just want to use modules at arbitrary places in your code, you should use `require`.